If I know the $q$th moment is finite for all $q \leq p$, can I say that the $p$th centered moment is finite?
Say I have a real-valued random variable, $X$ and let $p \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$. Say I also know that $E[X^q] < \infty$ for all $q \leq p$. Can I say that there centered $p$th moment,
$$E[ |X - E[X]|^p ],$$
is also finite? I know I can do this if $p \in \mathbb{N}$ since I can use binomial expansion but this doesn't work for $p \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0} \setminus \mathbb{N}$. I tried to do this the Taylor expansion but I didn't get anywhere.

Yes, just apply the inequality
$$
\vert a-b\vert^p\le(2^{p-1}\vee 1)(\vert a\vert^p+\vert b\vert^p).$$
EDIT: I changed $2^{p-1}$ to $2^{p-1}\vee 1$ to include the case $p\in(0,1)$.

Nice! Thank you!

Is it $2^p$ factor, as $p$ may be smaller than 1?

Indeed thanks. $2^p$ or $2^{p-1}\vee1$ if we want to be a bit sharper.
